# How to get current category name when having only the product ID

Tags: magento2, product, category, phtml, review

I want to get the current category name in a .phtml file, having only the product ID.
The product ID is fetched from reviews.

Note: I'm not running this on product page.

This is what I have now:

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$reviewData = $block->getAllRatingData();

foreach ($reviewData as $reviewKey => $reviewValue) {

$productId   = $reviewValue['entity_pk_value'];
$product     = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
$productName = $product->getName();
$productUrl  = $product->getProductUrl();

?>
<div>
    <span><?php echo $reviewValue['Grade']; ?></span><br>
    <span><a href="<?php echo($productUrl); ?>"><?php echo($productName); ?></a></span><br>
    <strong><?php echo $reviewValue['title']; ?></strong><br>
    <span><?php echo date_format(date_create($reviewValue['created_at']),"Y-m-d"); ?> 
    <?php echo $reviewValue['nickname']; ?></span><br>
    <em><?php echo $reviewValue['detail']; ?></em>
</div>
<br>
<?php
}
?>
```

Thanks,

Comment: on which page this code running?

Comment: @Charmi Patel => It's running from a module, and is called from a CMS page.

Comment: You want to category id from the product id which is fetched by the review. I mean in which categories assigned this product right?

Comment: Yes exactly, thats correct, and with the corresponding category name :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code. I update the code as per your requirement

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$reviewData = $block->getAllRatingData();

foreach ($reviewData as $reviewKey => $reviewValue) {
    $productId = $reviewValue['entity_pk_value'];
    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
    $productName = $product->getName();
    $productUrl = $product->getProductUrl();
    
    // Get category IDs associated with the product
    $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
    
    // Initialize an empty array to store category names
    $categoryNames = [];
    
    // Load category names based on category IDs
    foreach ($categoryIds as $categoryId) {
        $category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($categoryId);
        $categoryNames[] = $category->getName();
    }
    
    // Implode category names array into a string
    $categoryNamesString = implode(', ', $categoryNames);
    
    ?>
    <div>
        <span><?php echo $reviewValue['Grade']; ?></span><br>
        <span><a href="<?php echo($productUrl); ?>"><?php echo($productName); ?></a></span><br>
        <strong><?php echo $reviewValue['title']; ?></strong><br>
        <span><?php echo date_format(date_create($reviewValue['created_at']),"Y-m-d"); ?> 
        <?php echo $reviewValue['nickname']; ?></span><br>
        <em><?php echo $reviewValue['detail']; ?></em><br>
        <span>Categories: <?= $categoryNamesString; ?></span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <?php
}
?>
```

check this one and please tell me if you have any query

NOTE: replace objectmanager with corresponding dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Get category name from product anywhere.

```
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $categoryAllIds = $product->getCategoryIds();

    $names = [];    
    
    foreach ($categoryAllIds as $categoryId) {
        $category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($categoryId);
        $names[]  = $category->getName();
    }            
    $allCategory = implode(', ', $names);
    
    echo $allCategory;
}
?>
```

Note : Handle `$objectManager` according you.